# Galois Number Field Class Number

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The following question appeared on my final exam last week and I couldn't solve it.  I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts:

Let $L$ be a number field that is galois of degree $n > 1$. Let $p$ be the smallest prime factor of $n$. If $h$ is the class number of $L$ show that $h=1$ or $h \geq p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galois group $G$ acts on the class-group $C$. Let $c\in C$ be a non-trivial class.
If $G$ acts trivially on $C$, then $c^n$ is the identity in $C$
(it's the norm of $c$). So $c$ has order
a non-trivial factor of $n$, and so at least $p$.

Otherwise the number of elements in the orbit of $c$ under $G$ is a non-trivial
factor of $n$ and so at least $p$.